# Why not get xml file with $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, parsexml

I want to read XML file with below code but XML file does not pass to `parsexml` function and load error function. please help me why not worked successfully.

```
$(document).delegate('div .myBtn', 'click', function () {

    var current_data = "../aa.xml";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: current_data,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXML,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
            alert("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    $("#myModal").css("display", "block");
});

function parseXML(xml) {
    alert("okkkkkkkkk");
    var details = xml.getElementsByTagName("book");
    for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
       .
       .
       .
});
```

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: What's the error? What version of jQuery are you using ? `delegate` method is depreciated as of 3.0... you should be using `.on` instead.

Comment: `var current_data = "../aa.xml";` try to give the absolute path here.